# Is it possible to create indices for a View in MySQL, how to optimize performance?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a view that I created in MySQL that I created primarily to View my data in a simplified fashion, but I am wondering if I can use it in a query (apparently so), and if there is a way to index it or otherwise optimize performance.  It does OK now with not very many entries in the database, but it could get quite large.

The view is defined by:  CREATE VIEW master AS . . .

```
SELECT
   distinct hps.id AS id,
   languages.hp_id AS hp_id,
   hps.speciality AS speciality,
   subspecialities_hp_id.subspeciality AS subspeciality,
   languages.language AS language,
   hps.country AS country,
   hps.country_state AS country_state,
   br.body_region AS body_regions,
   symp.symptom AS symptoms,
   diseases.disease AS diseases,
   lic_ins_hp_id.license_country AS license_country,
   lic_ins_hp_id.license_state AS license_state,
   lic_ins_hp_id.license_active AS license_active,
   lic_ins_hp_id.insurance_country AS insurance_country,
   lic_ins_hp_id.insurance_state AS insurance_state,
   lic_ins_hp_id.insurance_active AS insurance_active
FROM ((((((hps left join languages on((hps.id = languages.hp_id))) left join body_hp_id BR on((hps.id = br.hp_id))) left join symptoms_hp_id SYMP on((hps.id = symp.hp_id))) left join diseases_hp_id DISEASES on((hps.id = diseases.hp_id))) left join lic_ins_hp_id on((hps.id = lic_ins_hp_id.hp_id))) left join subspecialities_hp_id on((hps.id = subspecialities_hp_id.hp_id)))
```

I can provide some samples from database, preferably screenshots, but basically, the id from the hps table is tied to the hp_id in the joined tables, so each id in hps can speak 1 to many languages, 0 to many body_regions, 0 to many symptoms, 0 to many diseases, etc.  For most, the number of entries in each category is going to be 0 to a few, but the view could get really large.  I've tried it with the view and a fairly complex query on the view and that takes about 10 msec per query, although with a fairly small database.  Just wondering if there is a way to index the view (MySQL) or otherwise optimize the queries, if 10 msec is long for a query, and if the query time will increase linearly or exponentially with database size.

I take it that View are meant to be just that, a way to visualize data and not to be used as a table for queries.

Comment: View is just an alias for a stored query. It is not backed up by data storage, so you should optimise it as if you optimised the query itself.

Comment: They can be used table-like for queries. For gets. Don't think of them of much more than that. But make them complicated with joins and backed by table indices as zerkms said. They are snapshots of the related table schemas at time of creation, can be fragile, and not work.